# Why test cases are showing error in this?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

```
import java.util.*;
public class football{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int top=-1;
    final int MAX=10000000;
    int stack[]=new int[MAX];
//based on stacks
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int cases,n,id;
    cases=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<cases;i++){
        n=sc.nextInt();
        id=sc.nextInt();
        if(top>=MAX){
            System.exit(0);
        }else{
            top++;
            stack[top]=id;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            char q;
            q=sc.next().charAt(0);
            if(q=='P'){
                id=sc.nextInt();
                top++;
                stack[top]=id;
            }else if(q=='B'){
                int temp=stack[top];
                top=top++;
                stack[top]=temp;
                continue;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Player "+stack[top]);

        }
    }
}
```

/*This is a question based on the player passing on hackerearth as who pases whom after N passes and i am not being able to pass all the testcases except the sample one, please suggest the error which can be rectified in order to solve this one. */

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: @guy i have no idea, what is the error, the sample test cases are not passing and showing this as a wrong answer although my sample test case is passed.

Comment: How do you expect us identify why the code is not producing the output it's expected to do, when we don't know *what* it is expected to do?

Comment: @Guy https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/stacks/basics-of-stacks/practice-problems/algorithm/the-football-fest-6/ 

is the link for the problem

Comment: @Andreas , just provided you the link bro, please check

Comment: I'm not sure what it's supposed to do, but the provided code executes without exception in my IDE.

Comment: Your `B` back logic doesn't work. 1) What do you believe `top=top++;` does, and why? --- 2) Rethink your `B` back logic, because you don't need a stack. You just need the current `ID` and the previous `ID`, because repeated `B` back moves will just pass the ball repeatedly between the last two players.

Comment: @Andreas this question is asked to be solved by stack which is why, secondly yeah i mistook that top=top++, which i resolved.

Comment: @TheHeadRush it was even executing perfectly in my IDE, but submitting on the given link is showing error.

Comment: @SwapnilSudhir Try removing the last `B` pass from the sample input, and your code will still print `Player 9`, when it should be `Player 99`. As I said. your `B` logic doesn't work.

Comment: @SwapnilSudhir It's true that the question is a challenge given in the context of Stacks, but that doesn't mean the code have to use a stack. If there is a better implementation, you can use it, and here there is. I think it's a bad challenge for a "Basics of Stacks" concept. Now if two consecutive `B` passes would pass back to player 63, who originally passed to player 99, then it would be a good Stack challenge, because you'd have to use a stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
}else if(q=='B'){
            int temp=stack[top-1];
            top++;
            stack[top]=temp;
            continue;
        }
```

this is what you need to but yes its not a good case for stack two simple variable is what you need to track the last possesion.